# Flutter - Dynamic list view not showing data

Tags: android, ios, mobile, dart, flutter

I've write a class for showing a list of person's name in my body content, but it is not showing anything at all.

My question is, how can I make it to dinamically show the persons loaded from the api?

this is my code for the class about:

```
import 'package:condos/api/http_client.dart';
import 'package:condos/api/query_string.dart';
import 'package:condos/api/response.dart';
import 'package:condos/person.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class About extends StatelessWidget {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient('http://www.mocky.io/v2/');
  String title = 'About';
  final TextEditingController eCtrl = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Person> persons = new List();
    Params params = new Params();
    params.add('page', '1');

    client
        .getPersons('5c096d492f00007d41637e36', params)
        .then((Response<List<Person>> response) {
          persons = response.content;
          print(persons[0].name);
        });
return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Dynamic Demo"),
    ),
    body: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          controller: eCtrl,
          onSubmitted: (text) {
            print(text);
            Person person =
            new Person.fromAny({"id": "1", "name": 'juan meme'});
            print(person.name);
            persons.add(person);
            eCtrl.clear();
          },
        ),
        new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: persons.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                  return new Text(persons[Index].name);
                }))
      ],
    ));
}
}
```

Sorry for the question, but i'm new with this framework.

Comment: Add shrinkwrap: true in Listview.builder

Comment: It's still not working... :( @anmol.majhail

Comment: what error do you get?